# Azure Data Factory upload Zip File to SFTP

Tags: azure-data-factory

I need some help pointing me in write direction. I have a zip file with CSV file inside the zip file. CSV file name is 'PRODDATA.CSV'. Zip File name is PRODDATA20210223.zip

When I use Copy Activity with ZipDeflate as source in the SFTP destination it creates a zip file with the proper name PRODDATA20210223.zip but inside the zip file it puts data_.txt inside the zip file. It doesn't retain the CSV file. The text file is actually is correct CSV format.

Can someone point what I'm doing wrong or how can I make sure the zip file created and inside it still retains the CSV extension and the name.

Answer (score 0):

I tested and repeat your error.

Please don't set the compression type ZipDeflate in Sink dataset.

Or you will get the output file like this:
[image]

The correct sink dataset settings:
[image]

[image]

Then the output file could be:
[image]

**Update:**

Source settings and dataset:
[image]

[image]

Please correct my if I misunderstand your question.

HTH.

Comment: Thanks for your input. I like the output but want to make sure how you set your source may be I’m doing mistake in there. My source file is a .zip file with zip deflate option set with csv delimiter type sink  is again csv delimiter but didn’t have zip deflate option my destination is sftp if you can share your source setting may be I will try the same. Based on your reply I will try again. TIA

Comment: @Nathan Sure, please see my update. I don't have SFTP, but it's same operation with storage.

Comment: Thanks @leon Yue I will test tomorrow and will update you going to do first to blob then SFTP will update here

Comment: @Nathan You're welcome. Is the issue solved now? If my answer is helpful for you, can you can accept it as answer? This can be beneficial to other community members. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Second screen shot for the Source .....

Answer (score 0):

[![enter image description here][1]][1]

Second screen shot for the Source .....
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/XXsWJ.png

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Sink 1st Screen Shot.... Creating Zip File...Then it worked

[image]